# jQuery Ganttchart with drag drop, sretchind and create functionality

Tags: jquery, gantt-chart

I want a panel using gantt chart to show bookings (Rooms on the Y-axis and dates on X-axis) with drag drop, stretching, and creating new events.I have found something similar https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/ but this is in angularjs, I want to use this kind of gantt chart in jQuery. Is there any such chart available?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. 
Try http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/ you can customize it for your needs.